# Crystal report Load Report Failed in vb.net after copying a report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have an original 2 reports:
offset.rpt and roto.rpt

I need to create a new design(putting new logo and changing colors) for the two reports.
I copy offset.rpt and named it offset_temp.rpt, I copy roto.rpt and named it roto_temp.rpt

this is my code:

```
Public Sub ViewReport()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Main.dgvColorTolerance.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim filePath As String
    If Main.Process = "ROTO" Then
        filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\roto.rpt"
        If Main.lblcheckuni.Text.Contains("NEW") Then
            filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\roto_temp.rpt"
        End If
    Else
        filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\offset.rpt"
        If Main.lblcheckuni.Text.Contains("NEW") Then
            filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\offset_temp.rpt"
        End If
    End If


    cryRpt.Load(filePath)
    cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula = " ({command.ID} = " & Main.dgvColorTolerance.Item(Main.dgvColorTolerance.Columns.Count - 1, i).Value & ")"
    cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sa_connection", "******")
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(85)
```

when I run it: Error message "Load Report Failed" when lblcheckuni.text contains "NEW" but if not, it runs fine.
I google it and some said maybe file is not exist. but It is exist.
Please help. Thank you

Comment: Try putting a stop on the If Main.lblcheckunit... line and then step through the code.  Does it drop into the if statement and try to assign the _temp.rpt to the filePath variable?

Comment: I saw my problem @APrough, the path is wrong, can you help me for the syntax of the path. the path is C:\Documents and Settings\administrator\Desktop\color_tolerance\ColorTolerance (Win App)\ColorTolerance\roto_temp.rpt

its not recommended if i put the whole path, right? what will be the syntax to shortcut this path so I dont need to edit the path every time I run this program in every local.. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps do Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) to get the Desktop path and build the rest onto it?

Answer (score 1):

To get the Desktop path

```
Dim desktop as string = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
filePath = desktop & "\color_tolerance\ColorTolerance (Win App)\ColorTolerance\" & reportName
```